# Whats wrong with my Mr_Meow = turtle.Turtle()

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to draw a flower with my turtle, while learning about how to make and use `Classes`. I'm trying to call `petal()` and pass `Mr_Meow` through it. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import turtle

def petal(Mr_Meow):
    a = Mr_Meow
    for i in range(4*9):
        Mr_Meow.left(60)
        a.forward(100)
        a.left(60)
        a.forward(100)
        a.left(60*2)
        a.forward(100)
        a.left(60)
        a.forward(100)
        a.right(10)
    a.backward(300)
    a.right(90)
    a.backward(100)
    a.forward(200)



def daraw():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor('red')
    Mr_Meow = turtle.Turtle()

    Mr_Meow.speed(10)
    petal(Mr_meow)
    window.exitonclick()


daraw()
```

--------------and here is the Error i get:

```
  File "/home/kd/pythonfiles/Movies.py", line 50
    for i in range(9*4):
                       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? "**inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation**"! Check your indentation.

Comment: @user2357112 I in all honesty I have no teacher and I'm just starting to learn. I actually do not understand the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! This is a very common (and *frustrating*) problem with learning Python.

Python is white-space dependent which means you must (for the most part) consistently use either spaces or tabs for your indentation.

This error is saying somewhere in your code you are using tabs, and other places you are using spaces for indentation. Open the code in a text editor (such as Notepad++ or Sublime text) and enable the option to show white space characters. For learning python I would recommend programming in an editor with this feature enabled at all times (at least for a while to get used to spotting this mistake).